# A file equals content of website?

Tags: java, file, java-io

I couldnt find out how to compare the content of a specific file to a content of a website.

This is the code I used to check, if it equals:

```
 private static boolean equals() {
    try {
        return new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filePath))).equals(getFile());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

filePath:

```
private static final String filePath = "test.txt";
```

getFile():

```
private static String getFile() {
    try {
        URL pageURL = new URL(simpleurl);
        URLConnection uc = pageURL.openConnection();
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(uc.getInputStream(), "UTF-8")) {
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                text.append(scanner.nextLine()).append("\n");
            }
        }
        return text.toString();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The method #equals() keeps returning false while the content matches the file.

Comment: Wouldn't it be because you swallowed all newlines and replaced them by `\n` for some unclear reason instead of untouching the original newlines which might actually have been `\r\n` instead? Wouldn't it be because you didn't check which encoding the response is originally in and blindly assumed it to be UTF-8 all the time? Wouldn't it be because you used `new String()` without specifying the charset? All in all, you should not be worrying about characters nor be massaging them into different characterbased formats at all. Just grab the content as `byte[]` and compare `byte[]` against `byte[]`.

Comment: I have just tested using `\r\n` and removing UTF-8 and it didn't work out. How would I grab the contents as byte[]?

Comment: @user2527967 for starters, I would drop the `Scanner` wrapping

Comment: @JanDvorak - what do you suggest for using to read content?

Comment: @user2527967 manipulating the `inputStream` directly is probably the best option. If not, I'd check other methods in `uc`

Answer (score 1):

You're unnecessarily massaging the bytes to characters and back and hereby losing information contained in the original bytes. Usually, you should only transform bytes to characters when you are interested in reading or manipulating the bytes on a per-character basis *and* you absolutely understand how character encodings work. Neither of those seems to be the case here. You should then just be reading and writing the raw and unmodified bytes instead of transforming them to characters.

To read an `InputStream` from `URL` into a `byte[]` (instead of `String`), one of the ways would be:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

try (InputStream input = url.openStream()) {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[10240];
    for (int length = 0; (length = input.read(buffer)) > 0;) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, length));
    }
}

byte[] contentFromURL = output.toByteArray();
```

*([Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toByteArray%28java.io.InputStream%29) and [Google Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/ByteStreams.html#toByteArray%28java.io.InputStream%29) have oneliner methods for this)*

Note that when you intend to save the `byte[]` into a file, then you should merely be doing as follows without the need to massage them into characters by `new String()` or so:

```
Files.write(path, contentFromURL);
```

Also note that when you intend to save any `InputStream` immediately into a file without the need for an intermediairy `byte[]`, then you should be doing this in first place:

```
try (InputStream input = url.openStream()) {
    Files.copy(input, path);
}
```

Either way, you end up with a file containing **exactly** the same bytes as originally obtained. Based on your code, you already know that you can get the `byte[]` out of it as follows:

```
byte[] contentFromFile = Files.readAllBytes(path);
```

If you have the content as `byte[]` and want to compare it against another `byte[]`, then you should just be using [`Arrays#equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals%28byte%5B%5D,%20byte%5B%5D%29) without massaging them to `String`s:

```
Arrays.equals(contentFromURL, contentFromFile);
```

That's all. There is no need to explicitly read it using a character encoding of which you haven't even confirmed that the HTTP response is really been encoded in *that* encoding, and there is also no need to swallow all newlines and replace them by a fixed one of which you haven't even confirmed that the HTTP response is really using *that* as newline character.

Answer (score 0):

If the content realy matches "test.txt" should be also UTF-8 and you should read it with

```
new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filePath)), "UTF-8")
```

May work without it on a Linux-system but on windows it won't. But in either case you should specify the expected encoding.